# What is the significance of Roy Batty's fingernails in "Blade Runner" (1982)?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner

I just rewatched *Blade Runner* and noticed there are multiple shots of Roy Batty's fingernails, which are very short as if they've been chewed or picked at excessively.

Is this just included to show his existential anxiety, or is there some greater significance to it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on my recollection, and especially the shot in which he completely peels off one nail, this seemed intended to show how close he was to obsolescence death, already on borrowed time, as it were, with only days, then hours, then minutes before he would die.